# Why was it necessary to prove convergence first in this problem?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, analytic-functions

> Let $f$ be analytical with power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n $
> and convergence radius $R>0$. Let $X$ be a  Banach space and $T\in
>  B(X)$ (bounded from $X$ to itself) such that $||T||<R$. Prove that
> $f(T):=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^N a_nT^n$ is a bounded operator
> and find $||f(T)||$.

In the proof, it was first proven that $f(T)$ is well defined and bounded. Only then the author went on to computing $||f(T)||$. When I attempted to solve this myself, I concluded that it is already well defined since the hypothesis includes the fact that series converges ($||T||<R$ so it's in the convergence radius, no?), and went directly to computing $||f(T)||$ by claiming the following:

$$ ||f(T)|| = \lim_{N\to \infty}|| \sum_{n=0}^N a_n T^n|| \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| ||T||^n$$

where the first transition is by continuity of the norm **and the fact that the series converges for this T**, and the second is the triangle inequality and again the fact that $T$ is within the radius of convergence (absolute convergence in the norm).

What is wrong with my reasoning? Why would I first have to claim that $f(T)$ is well defined (converges) if I already know that...? Is it perhaps a case of the *order* of convergence that could be different? (I do not recall much about analytic functions and their power series etc., so I must be missing something in this respect).

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot just plug in an operator into the equation $f(z)=\sum a_nz^{n}$ without knowing that $f(T)$ even exists. You can only plug in values of $z$ in the complex plane. You can put $z=\|T\|$ but not $z=T$.

Comment: So $f$ is a complex function of a complex variable, and you want to plug an *operator* into it. Well, that does require some justification!

Answer (score 1):

In a Banach space $Y,$ if the series $\sum y_n$ is absolutely convergent, i.e. $\sum \|y_n\|<\infty$, then it is convergent. In your case $Y=B(X)$ and $y_n=a_nT^n.$ We have
$$\sum \|y_n\|=\sum |a_n|\,\|T^n\|\le \sum |a_n|\,\|T\|^n<\infty $$ as $\|T\|<R.$
Hence the series $f(T):=\sum a_n T^n$ is convergent.

**Remark** I do not think it is possible to find a norm $f(T)$ explicitly in terms of $f$ and  $\|T\|.$ In particular there is no explicit expression for the norm $\|T^2\|$ in terms of $\|T\|.$ It is possible to find the spectral radius of $f(T)$ in terms of $f$ and $\sigma(T).$ Namely
$$r(f(T))=\max\{|f(z)|\,:\, z\in \sigma(T)\}$$

Comment: To illustrate Ryszard's claim about $\|T^2\|$, consider $T_1=\pmatrix { 1&0\cr 0&0 }$ in relation to $T_2=\pmatrix { 0&1\cr 0&0 }$.  Both have norm 1, but their squares do not have the same norm.

Comment: Nevertheless, in analysis, the expression "find the norm" often stands for "majorize the norm", so I think the estimate given by the OP is acceptable.